# Negative margin-bottom is completely ignored in FF and IE. Is this a bug?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Let me start by saying that I do not need help *working around* this issue - I can easily solve my specific problem myself. But I do need help understanding *why* it happens - and potentially establish that it is in fact a bug, so I can report it.

The issue is that a parent container with `overflow:hidden` containing a child with a negative `margin-bottom`, which in turn contains one or more `float`ed items followed by a `clear` (ie. it's height is depends on the floating children)... seems to completely ignore the negative bottom margin.

I would not expect the content of the child div to play any role for the negative bottom margin... no matter what is inside that child I would expect the negative margin to be respected, and the content to be "cut off" by the parent's `overflow: hidden`.

> **TL;DR**: There is a more minimalistic example below...

This example shows the problem in FF and IE - but works exactly as I would expect in chrome:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: tomato;
}

.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: goldenrod;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 12.5%;
  float: left;
}

.parent.overflow_visible {
  overflow: visible;
}

.child {
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px; /* THIS ONE has no effect in FF and IE */
}

.float {
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border-top: 15px solid green;
  border-bottom: 15px solid green;
  width: 100%;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.clear_below {
  clear: both;
  background: yellow;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent overflow_visible">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear_below"></div>
```

The box on the right should have 5px borders on both top and bottom, and the yellow bar below the boxes should overlap with the "fat" bottom border on the left box and be right below the "slim" bottom border on the right.

**Note that most of this is just to clearly visualize it** - the problem itself can be reproduced with a far less verbose example:

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden">
  <div style="margin-bottom: -10px">
    <div style="float: left">float</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the "grand-children" are *not* floated the problem does not occur:

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden">
  <div style="margin-bottom: -60px">
    <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone provide a sane explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: That's just how float works: the browser clears the float by internally increasing the top margin of the clearing element until its top is flush with the bottom of the floating one.

Comment: @MrLister Err... I'm not confused about how floats work (or at least I don't think I am). The `clear` obviously **should** be below to float itself, and therefore extend the child's bottom to below the float... But that should **not** prevent the negative bottom margin on the child from having any effect at all... so the parent's bottom should be 10px **above** the child's bottom (and the clear). All details aside, there is a very clear difference in rendering between Chrome and firefox, which should not be the case if this was *"just how float works"*.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a bug in Chrome.

Let's break down your example from the top level. Your `.parent` containers are block formatting context roots because they are `float`ing ([section 9.4.1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#block-formatting) of the CSS2.x spec). Their specified `height` is `auto` (the default value). According to the [section 10.6.7](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#root-height),

> ...if the element has any floating descendants whose bottom margin
>   edge is below the element's bottom content edge, then **the height is
>   increased to include those edges**

The bottom margin edge of the floating descendants (the `.float` elements) is their bottom border edge, since their own bottom margin is zero. The spec doesn't say anything about intermediate block wrappers of the floating descendants, so the fact that the `.child` elements have smaller height than `.float` elements shouldn't affect the height of the container, and the resulting container height should be determined by the height of floating elements (including their borders). This is what we see in other browsers, and this is what we see in Chrome, too, if we remove the `clear: both;` property from the `.clear` element.

However, the presence of the `clear`ing block somehow changes the behavior of the container in Chrome. It seems that the browser "decides" that there is some content *below* the floating element, and starts to act as if the height was determined by that content, "forgetting" that the bottom border of the floating element is actually below the bottom content edge of the container itself (which is at the bottom margin edge of the `.child`).

So, if you want to clip the floating descendants of the block formatting context root, it's better to set the negative margins to these floating elements themselves.

Comment: I find it super counter-intuitive, so I'm trying hard to argue... I've read through 10.6.7 several times, and tried to find something that contradicts your conclusion. I'm not used to reading these things... But:  "Only floats that participate in this block formatting context are taken into account". The "intermediate block wrappers" you refer to (ie. what I call the `.child`)... should that not establish a *new* block formatting context - meaning the bug is in fact in FF...?

Comment: It would establish the new BFC if it had either `display:flow-root/inline-block/table/table-cell/flex/grid`, `overflow:hidden/auto`, `float: left/right`, any `column-count`, or if it were the `fieldset` element. But in your example it is just a regular block that participates in its parent BFC along with its descendants.

Comment: And I agree, it's super counter-intuitive. In my opinion, so is almost everything about floats/clearing in CSS!

Comment: That is very true :p